# Aggregate while subtracting values in R

Tags: r

If I have two data frames in R (let's call them `df1` and `df2` respectively) such as

```
> df1
state num1
   AL 22
   AK 49
   AZ 48
   AR 25
```

and

```
> df2
state num2
   AK 2
   AZ 3
   AR 4
   CA 5
```

how do I aggregate those data frames while subtracting the values to form something like

```
state num3
   AL 22
   AK 47
   AZ 45
   AR 21
   CA -5
```

Note: the key values are not the same in the data frames; the data frames have different numbers of rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be an easier way to get there, but here's a possibility.  We can `merge()` the two data frames, then subtract the columns after replacing the `NA` values with zero.

```
m <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)
cbind(m[1], num3 = with(replace(m, is.na(m), 0L), num1 - num2))
#   state num3
# 1    AK   47
# 2    AL   22
# 3    AR   21
# 4    AZ   45
# 5    CA   -5
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(state = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AL", "AR", "AZ"), class = "factor"), num1 = c(22L, 49L, 48L, 
25L)), .Names = c("state", "num1"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(state = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AR", "AZ", "CA"), class = "factor"), num2 = 2:5), .Names = c("state", 
"num2"), row.names = 2:5, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

One way with dplyr would be the following. You combine the two data frame with `full_join`. Then, you replace NA with 0. Then, you handle the subtraction, which is done in the `mutate()` part. Finally, choose the necessary columns with `select()`.

DATA

```
mydf1 <- structure(list(state = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AL", "AR", "AZ"), class = "factor"), num1 = c(22L, 49L, 48L, 
25L)), .Names = c("state", "num1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

mydf2 <- structure(list(state = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AR", "AZ", "CA"), class = "factor"), num2 = 2:5), .Names = c("state", 
"num2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

CODE

```
full_join(mydf1, mydf2, by = c("state" = "state")) %>%
mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(. %in% NA), 0)), num1:num2) %>%
mutate(num3 = num1 - num2) %>%
select(state, num3)

#  state num3
#1    AL   22
#2    AK   47
#3    AZ   45
#4    AR   21
#5    CA   -5
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merging the data frames, combining the rows. First we change the  sign of the column `num2` and then we aggregate the results by state:

Base package:

```
aggregate(num1 ~ state, 
          data = rbind(df1, setNames(data.frame(df2[1], -df2[2]), names(df1))), 
          FUN = sum)
```

Output:

```
  state num1
1    AK   47
2    AL   22
3    AR   21
4    AZ   45
5    CA   -5
```

dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
rbind(df1, setNames(data.frame(df2[1], -df2[2]), names(df1))) %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(num1))
```